# why cant an Int and a floating point number be added in haskell

Tags: haskell

why wont this work :-

```
(length [1,2,3,4]) + 3.2
```

while this works:-

```
2+3.3
```

I understand that in the first case the result is an Int+Float but is that not the same in the second case too, or does Haskell automatically infer the type in the second case to be :- Num+Num whereas it does not do that in the first case?

Comment: Haskell doesn't to implicit conversions.  Why?  Well, they complicate the type system, but they are also potentially unsafe.  There's no guarantee that converting an `Int` to a `Float` will not lose accuracy.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Haskell *never* does implicit type conversion for you. `+` only ever works on two numbers of the same type, and gives you that type as the result as well. Any other usage of `+` is an error, as you saw with your `(length [1,2,3,4]) + 3.2` example.

However, numeric literals are overloaded in Haskell. `2` could be any numeric type, and `3.3` could be any fractional type. So when Haskell sees the expression `2 + 3.3` it can try to find a type which is both "numeric" and "fractional", and treat both numbers as that type so that the addition will work.

Speaking more precisely, `+` has the type `Num a => a -> a -> a`. `2` on its own is of type `Num a => a` and `3.3` on its own is of type `Fractional a => a`. Putting those 3 types together, the in the expression `2 + 3.3` both numbers can be given the type `Fractional a => a`, because all `Fractional` types are also `Num` types, and this then also satisfies the type of `+`. (If you type this expression into GHCi the `a` gets filled in as `Double`, because GHC has to default the type to *something* in order to evaluate it)

In the expression `(length [1,2,3,4]) + 3.2`, the `3.2` is still overloaded (and in isolation would have type `Fractional a => a`). But `length [1,2,3,4]` has type `Int`. Since one side is a fixed concrete type, the only way to satisfy the type for `+` would be to fill in the `a` on the other type with `Int`, but that violates the `Fractional` constraint; there's no way for `3.2` to be an `Int`. So this expression is not well-typed.

However, any `Integral` type (of which `Int` is one) can be converted to *any* `Num` type by applying `fromIntegral` (this is actually how the integer literals like `2` can be treated as any numeric type). So `(fromIntegral $ length [1,2,3,4]) + 3.2` will work.

Answer (score 10):

In the first case, as you mentioned, `length [1,2,3,4]` is explicitly an `Int` and can't be converted implicitly into a `Float` or into any `Fractional` instance. While in the second, there is no explicit typing, thus Haskell can infer that the good type is an instance of `Fractional`. You can see how numeric literal are handled by the compiler in [the corresponding section (§6.4.1) of the Haskell 2010 report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1360006.4.1).

A workaround: `(fromIntegral $ length [1,2,3,4]) + 3.2`

Answer (score 8):

Integer literals, such as `2` in your second example, are implicitly treated as `fromInteger 2` by the compiler. This means they are converted to any required numeric type, because `fromInteger` is polymorphic in its return type; in this case, `Float` is used. However, `length [1,2,3,4]` is of type `Int`, and not a literal, so you need to convert its value explicitly.