# Haskell: Operations on Double and Int give error "couldn't match expected type"

Tags: haskell, types, instance

I'm writing a interpreter for my own language and I have an abstract syntax tree which has this type:

```
data Expression = 
  PInt Int
  | PFloat Double
  | PString String
  | PChar Char
  | PBool Bool
  | Var String
  | Unbound String String
  | Unary String Expression
  | Binary String Expression Expression
  | Call Expression [Expression]
  | Lambda Expression
  | Assign String Expression Expression
  | Conditional Expression Expression Expression
  deriving Eq
```

I'm trying to write an instance of Num for my class so that I can use existing machinery for numerical operations. Here's what I've written:

```
instance Num Expression where
   PInt a + PInt b = PInt $ a + b
   PInt a + PFloat b = PFloat $ a + b
   PFloat a + PInt b = PFloat $ a + b
   PFloat a + PFloat b = PFloat $ a + b
   _ + _ = undefined
   PInt a - PInt b = PInt $ a - b
   PInt a - PFloat b = PFloat $ a - b
   PFloat a - PInt b = PFloat $ a - b
   PFloat a - PFloat b = PFloat $ a - b
   _ - _ = undefined
   PInt a * PInt b = PInt $ a * b
   PInt a * PFloat b = PFloat $ a * b
   PFloat a * PInt b = PFloat $ a * b
   PFloat a * PFloat b = PFloat $ a * b
   _ * _ = undefined
   negate (PInt a) = PInt (-a)
   negate (PFloat a) = PFloat (-a)
   negate _ = undefined
   abs (PInt a) = PInt $ abs a
   abs (PFloat a) = PFloat $ abs a
   abs _ = undefined
   signum (PInt a) = PInt $ signum a
   signum (PFloat a) = PFloat $ signum a
   signum _ = undefined
   fromInteger i = (PInt $ fromInteger i)
```

This gives me errors specifically in the places where I've combined ints and floats.

```
Prelude> :load AST.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling AST          ( AST.hs, interpreted )

AST.hs:38:36:
    Couldn't match expected type `Double' with actual type `Int'
    In the first argument of `(+)', namely `a'
    In the first argument of `PFloat', namely `(a + b)'
    In the expression: PFloat (a + b)

AST.hs:39:37:
    Couldn't match expected type `Double' with actual type `Int'
    In the second argument of `(+)', namely `b'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `a + b'
    In the expression: PFloat $ a + b

AST.hs:43:33:
    Couldn't match expected type `Double' with actual type `Int'
    In the first argument of `(-)', namely `a'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `a - b'
    In the expression: PFloat $ a - b

AST.hs:44:37:
    Couldn't match expected type `Double' with actual type `Int'
    In the second argument of `(-)', namely `b'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `a - b'
    In the expression: PFloat $ a - b

AST.hs:48:33:
    Couldn't match expected type `Double' with actual type `Int'
    In the first argument of `(*)', namely `a'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `a * b'
    In the expression: PFloat $ a * b

AST.hs:49:37:
    Couldn't match expected type `Double' with actual type `Int'
    In the second argument of `(*)', namely `b'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `a * b'
    In the expression: PFloat $ a * b
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

This doesn't make sense to me, since the type of an Int + Double in Haskell is a Double, so a + b should resolve to a Double, and since the constructor for a PFloat takes a Double, no problem... why is this not the case?

Resolved: using `fromIntegral` in front of the variables of type `Int` fixes it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [why cant an Int and a floating point number be added in haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120789/why-cant-an-int-and-a-floating-point-number-be-added-in-haskell)

Comment: In short, “the type of an Int + Double in Haskell is a Double” is wrong. You have to explicitly convert the `Int`.

Comment: @chirlu That still seems to produce errors:
`PInt a + PFloat b = PFloat ((a + b) :: Double)`
and
`(PInt a) + (PFloat b) = PFloat ((a::Double) + b)`

EDIT: OK, using `fromIntegral` does it. Thanks chirlu!

Comment: Use `fromIntegral a + b`. See the linked question (possible duplicate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mathematical operators in the Num typeclass expect both of their arguments to have the same type, so you'll have to convert the Int to a Double using `fromIntegral` before you can add them together.

For example, replace this

```
PInt a + PFloat b = PFloat $ a + b
```

with this

```
PInt a + PFloat b = PFloat $ fromIntegral a + b
```