# Can't define a function taking an Int and a Float

Tags: haskell, type-mismatch

`a.hs` file has:

```
a :: Float -> Int -> Int
a b c = b + c
```

load it in ghci, the error is:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘Float’
```

and

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Float’ with actual type ‘Int’
```

If the parameter and the result is both int or float, then it works.

Why is that? Thanks!

Comment: You can't add `Int` and `Floats` without converting to the same type. `a b c = b + fromIntegral c` should work if you change the returning type to `Float`. If you want to keep returning an `Int`, just round your `Float`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why cant an Int and a floating point number be added in haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120789/why-cant-an-int-and-a-floating-point-number-be-added-in-haskell)

Comment: Unlike some other languages, Haskell never "promotes" or "converts" a numeric type to another automatically. You have to ask for the conversion explicitly using e.g. `fromIntegral`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type signature for [`(+)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-43-) is:

`(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`

Which means that both arguments (your `b` and `c`) must be of the same type.

As Ismor commented, you can use [`fromIntegral`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral):

`fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`

to convert `c` from `Int` to `Float` and get your function to typecheck.